# php 5.3.6 breaks my regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

Weird things happened when a website I am working on got moved to another server with newer version of PHP. The regex that was working normally on 3 other different servers refuses to work, returns 0 all the time.
This is the original regex:

```
/\A(?P<text>[[:alpha:]]{4})[[:space:]](?P<password>[\p{L}\p{N}]{3,})[[:space:]](?P<digit1>[[:digit:]]{2,4})[[:space:]](?P<digit2>[[:digit:]]{1,2})\z/u
```

password had to be unicode, before it was just [[:alnum:]] but there were some problems with clients.
And these are the ones I tried to no avail:

```
/\A(?<text>[[:alpha:]]{4}) (?<password>[[:alnum:]]{3,}) (?<digit1>[[:digit:]]{2,4}) (?<digit2>[[:digit:]]{1,2})\z/u
/\A(?<text>[\p{L}]{4}) (?<password>[\p{L}\p{N}]{3,}) (?<digit1>\d{2,4}) (?<digit2>\d{1,2})\z/u
```

Example text: `ABCD 1a2b3c 100 50`

All of these were tested on http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php and worked perfectly.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? I know it might not be the prettiest regex you've seen but it works (or at least worked until now) just like expected. Right now I'm blaming the PHP (lol).

Edit: tested the last pattern on these sites:
* http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/
* http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php
* http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm
* http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php
and on some others where it allowed to type my regex fully myself, with slashes and `u` flag.
In all of these websites it worked, but on some others I checked it didn't, same as my server.

PCRE is unicode-enabled...

Edit: seems that sysadmins changed something after all... didn't work until 10 minutes earlier :/ Somebody close this question, all of the regexes now work.

Comment: This is probably better asked at the PHP forums. Maybe you can file a bug report there providing the exact behavior (actual/expected) to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Well, I want to be sure it is a problem in PHP before I go there. If it is my regex pattern that is wrong then PHP is not to be blamed...

Comment: If "nothing" else has changed and the regex works on 3 other servers AND in an independent regex program - the problem should be somewhere else, I guess. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check your PCRE extension version (phpinfo() -> PCRE Library Version). Some servers have < 8, and version >= 8 only supports unicode.

[Here](http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/) is a good example on how to fix the problem on CentOS with PHP 5.2, you can check it with PHP 5.3 also.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thx. Edit: yeeeah, we have V6.6 of Feb. 2006 there... Weird really, newest PHP and such an old library.

Comment: It's not a problem from PHP - it depends on linux distribution you are using. If the default is CentOS - they always leave 6.6 the default and PHP only uses that.

Comment: Ahhh... yes, we have CentOS on that server... But we can always upgrade that library, no?

Comment: Yes you can, but I think it's not in the default package repository.

Comment: Yeeah, just contacted the sysadmins of that server and they say CentOS doesn't support PCRE higher than 6.6... Fortunately I found some nice links and guides on how to fix it, just gotta get them to do it.

Comment: Ok, they say that Unicode properties support is already enabled in the PCRE... Weird, I've tried on many online testers and on some it works, on some it doesn't.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link on how to fix this and how to test it.

Comment: Problem got solved after all... Damn sysadmins told that everything is as it should be but things only started working 10 minutes ago. At least they work now.